# How to apply a function on every element of all elements in a list in R

Tags: r, list, apply

I have a list containing matrices of the same size in R. I would like to apply a function over the same element of all matrices. Example:

```
> a <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)
> b <- matrix(5:8, ncol = 2)
> c <- list(a,b)
> c
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
```

Now I want to apply the mean function and would like to get a matrix like that:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    5
[2,]    4    6
```

Comment: In this simple example, you could just try `d = (a + b) / 2` and it would return the desired matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One conceptual way to do this would be to sum up the matrices and then take the average value of each entry.  Try using `Reduce`:

```
Reduce('+', c) / length(c)
```

**Output:**

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    5
[2,]    4    6
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to construct an array and then use `apply`.

*step 1: constructing the array.*
Using the `abind` library and `do.call`, you can do this:

```
library(abind)
myArray <- do.call(function(...) abind(..., along=3), c)
```

Using base R, you can strip out the structure and then rebuild it like this:

```
myArray <- array(unlist(c), dim=c(dim(a), length(c)))
```

In both instances, these return the desired array

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
```

*step 2: use `apply` to calculate the mean along the first and second dimensions.*

```
apply(myArray, 1:2, mean)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    5
[2,]    4    6
```

This will be more flexible than `Reduce`, since you can swap out many more functions, but it will be slower for this particular application.